# iTunes Connect web login does not work

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

iTunes Connect does not work on the desktop. It shows spinner (tested on all browsers).

Is there a workaround or a different way to login?

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround and a way to login to iTunes Connect when the web login is not available:

1. Go to Apple Developer [Member Center](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/), and login there.
2. Once logged in, go to [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com). You should be logged in here, too.